# How to read spring-application-context.xml and AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext both in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, app-config, web.xml, spring-annotations, applicationcontext

In case I want to read bean definitions from spring-application-context.xml, I would do this in web.xml file.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In case I want to read bean definitions through Java Configuration Class (AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext), I would do this in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.package.MyConfigAnnotatedClass
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

How do I use both in my application. like reading beans from both configuration xml file and annotated class.

Is there a way to load spring beans in xml file while we are using AppConfigAnnotatedClass to instantiate/use rest of the beans.

**This didnt work**

Xml file defines bean as

```
<bean name="mybean" class="org.somepackage.MyBean"/>
```

Java Class Imports Resources as

```
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:some-other-context.xml"})
@Configuration
public class MyConfigAnnotatedClass { 
    @Inject
    MyBean mybean;
}
```

But mybean value is always null which ofcourse will give nullpointerexception when calling method on mybean.

Answer (score 4):

You can annotate your `@Configuration` class with

```
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:some-other-context.xml"})
@Configuration
public class MyConfigAnnotatedClass { 
    ...
}
```

to have it import `<beans>` type xml contexts.

You can do the same thing the other way around. Your `@Configuration` class is also a `@Component`. If you have a `<component-scan>` that includes its package, all its declared beans will be added to the context. Alternatively, you can do

```
<bean name="myAdditionalConfig" class="org.somepackage.MyConfigAnnotatedClass" />
```

---

Note that `package` cannot be used as a name in the package structure.

Comment: @Suvasis  XML might not show properly in comments. Please edit your question and add it as code there.

Comment: I have edited my question showing what I have tried but did not work. Could you tell me how did you import the bean in @Configuration class. or where did you place your xml file.

Comment: @Suvasis If `MyConfigAnnotatedClass` is the class you've specified in the `contextConfigLocation` param, then what you have should work. This `xml` file should be a separate from the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.